# auto fold for C++ sources and headers

Tags: c++, vim, folding, spf13vim

I have heard that Vim has a built-in support of folding for the files written in various programming languages. Particularly I'm interested in cpp, h, hpp files. I would like to achieve such a behavior of Vim when all the function definitions are folded by default in every newly opened source file. I don't want to create every fold manually with `zF`.

I added the following lines to the end of `~/.vimrc` file (which was inherited from [spf13-vim distribution](http://vim.spf13.com/)):

```
set foldenable
autocmd FileType c,cpp,h,hpp setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

Unfortunately that did not resulted to the desired behaviour. All the files look just the same, and my attempt to hide the function with `zc` combo leads to error:

> E490: No fold found

I would be glad if someone could explain how to enable folding by default in Vim 7.4.

**UPD:** The code above works good, but there is still an issue with the recently opened files. Say we work on the project called 'sc-client-server' and we've just appended those two lines to ~/.vimrc and now ready to get back to the last edited file:

```
$ vim ~/.vimrc                                   //Modify config
$ reboot
$ vim ~/progs/sc-client-server/src/st.cpp        //No fold found. BUT: 
$ cp ~/progs/sc-client-server/src/st.cpp  /tmp
$ vim /tmp/st.cpp                                //Auto fold works fine. OR:
$ cd ~/progs/sc-client-server/src/ && mv src source
$ vim ~/progs/sc-client-server/source/st.cpp     //Auto fold works fine.
```

Is there any kind of cache or memory inside of Vim that prevents the desired file representation?

**Answer**
Remove all (or specific for you) files from `~/.vimviews` folder.

*To the off-topic voters* https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user/25930#25930?newreg=00a4918bba924cfa8b1d6a3e82061672

Comment: I recommend you the [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) plugin.  

Its a code-completion system based on the Clang analysis engine.

Comment: This is a question solely about Vim configuration. Not programming related, off-topic on SO. @Manu343726: He's asking about folding, not code completion.

Comment: @Manu343726, unfortunately I am forced to use quite old Linux distribution (RHEL 6.4) which does not provide actual Clang version.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: I don't know about the spf13-vim distribution, but the `.vimrc` settings you posted work perfectly for me (Vim7.3). Which version of Vim are we talking about? Have you tried those settings on a vanilla Vim setup (i.e. backing up the spf13 `.vimrc` and trying those settings in a clean one)?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: ...and while not exactly an answer to your question, I found having a tag list (taglist plugin, http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net) to be much more comfortable than folding. YMMV.

Comment: @DevSolar, the version is 7.4. I found it very strange that some cpp files are opened with the desired "folded" representation while the others are still lacking folds. Have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: So they are **not** looking all the same? Which ones are folded? Which ones are not? What does either group have in common?

Comment: @DevSolar, please look through the update of the topic.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: There are various possibilities where and how folds could be cached, especially when you've been folding before and after you installed that spf13 distribution. Look for `~/.vim*` files and directories. That's about as much as I could help you.

Comment: So, what is the question now?

Comment: @Jacobo de Vera, everything is clear now

Comment: @VitalyIsaev please don't add an answer as an edit to your question. The proper way to do it is to post an actual answer. You are allowed (even encouraged) to answer your own question, but not as an edit to the question.